# A bounded linear operator from $X ^*\rightarrow Y^*$ is weak*-weak* continuous iff It is the adjoint of some Bounded linear operator $X\rightarrow Y$

Tags: functional-analysis

*(this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832836/a-linear-map-sy-to-x-is-weak-continuous-if-and-only-if-s-t-for-so) since the latter only addresses the situation in the case of Banach spaces)*

Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces and $B:Y^*\rightarrow X^*$ a linear operator. We want to show that $B$ is $weak*-weak*$ continuous iff $B=A^*$ for some $A \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$.

My intial idea was to set $A=\iota^{-1}_Y\circ B^{*}\circ\iota_X$ where $\iota:X \rightarrow X^{**}$ is the canonical embedding $x \mapsto ev_x$, the evaluation map of $x$ ie $\iota(x)f=f(x)$. I think this will work except how can I know $\iota^{-1}$ is defined (that is, how can I guarantee $B^*(\iota(x)) \in \iota (Y))?$ If this where Banach space I would be done, but I don't know what to do in this setting. Am I even on the right track?

EDIT: I found [A linear map $S:Y^*\to X^*$ is weak$^*$ continuous if and only if $S=T^*$ for some $T\in B(X,Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832836/a-linear-map-sy-to-x-is-weak-continuous-if-and-only-if-s-t-for-so) but I'm not clear on the setting. It looks to me (admitly naively) they are assuming reflexivity of $Y$ (and, or that $Y$ Banach, which I don't have?

Comment: Does this question answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246979/adjoint-operator-in-banach-space

Comment: Hm,  ''Hence, ∃!y∈Y such that
B(f)(x)=f(y)∀f∈Y∗
(This is a short lemma, that perhaps has been proved before in the textbook)?'' <- This may not be true in general normed spaces? (Its certainly true that if $Y$ is reflexive)

Comment: It is also true in Banach spaces a-la https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183869/weak-continuous-linear-functional-is-in-the-predual

Comment: I think it works in any normed linear space. What does not, however, is the next step using the closed graph theorem, which needs completeness.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets Can you elaborate on why you think it works in general normed spaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A linear map $S:Y^*\to X^*$ is weak$^*$ continuous if and only if $S=T^*$ for som $T\in B(X,Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832836/a-linear-map-sy-to-x-is-weak-continuous-if-and-only-if-s-t-for-so)

Comment: @CalvinKhor That response is in the context of Banach spaces. It's still controversial whether or not such an arguement works on normed spaces (see the counter-example below). I think it does work, but I cannot find an error Martin Argerami's counter-example.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the comment (retracted close vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Edited 2024-02-03)*

The result is true even if $Y$ is not complete. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/501743/muselive) for a proof. The proof uses the Closed Graph Theorem, but it does so on the duals, which are Banach even if $X,Y$ aren't.

The counterexample in my original answer was wrong. The subtlety, noted in the comments by jantomico, is that while we have results like the dual of a normed space and the dual of its closure is the same, the weak$^*$-topology **does** depend on whether one takes the closure or not. In other words, in the context of the wrong example below, $\sigma(X^*,X)$ and $\sigma(X^*,\overline X)$ are not the same topology when $X$ is not complete.

I'm leaving the wrong example below, because it is mentioned in many comments, so that the conversation makes sense.

---

**Warning: The example below is WRONG.** The map $S$ constructed in the example is $\sigma(Y^*,\overline Y)-\sigma(X^*,\overline X)$ continuous, but it is **not** $\sigma(Y^*,Y)-\sigma(X^*,X)$ continuous, which is what was asked.

For instance take $X=Y\subset\ell^1$ be
$$
X=Y=\{x\in\ell^1:\ \exists n_0:\ n\geq n_0\implies x(n)=0\}. 
$$
Because $X$ and $Y$ are dense in $\ell^1$, we have $X^*=Y^*=\ell^\infty$.

Define $S:Y^*\to X^*$, that is $S:\ell^\infty\to\ell^\infty$ by
$$
Sw=\big(\sum_n\frac{w(n)}{n^2},0,0,\ldots\big).
$$
If $w_j\to0$ weak$^*$, this means that $\sum_nw_j(n)y(n)\to0$ for all $y\in Y$. In particular $\sum_n\frac{w_j(n)}{n^2}\to0$, and it follows $S$ is weak$^*$-weak$^*$ continuous.

If we had $S=T^*$, with $T\in \mathcal L(X,Y)$ this would mean that, for each $w\in\ell^\infty$ and $x\in X$,
$$
(Sw)x=w(Tx). 
$$
This translates to
$$
\sum_n\frac{w(n)x(1)}{n^2}=\sum_nw(n)\,(Tx)(n).
$$
As this should work for all $w\in\ell^\infty$, it follows that we need
$$
Tx=\bigg(\frac{x(1)}{n^2}\bigg)_n.
$$
But then $Tx\not\in Y$ for any nonzero $x$, and so $T\not\in \mathcal L(X,Y)$.

Comment: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/funcana-ams.pdf- The question appears here on page 190 (202 in the pdf). Could I be misunderstanding/misreading?

Comment: Top of the page 4.5.4 b

Comment: No, you are not misunderstanding. Either they are wrong, or my example is wrong. Note that in Conway's book the exercise requires both $X$ and $Y$ to be Banach.

Comment: Also I'm finding it difficult to find where exactly you need completeness of $Y$ in your proof (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832836/a-linear-map-sy-to-x-is-weak-continuous-if-and-only-if-s-t-for-so). A comment suggests it is in the invoking of closed graph theorm, but I thought dual spaces where always Banach spaces? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#:~:text=Dual%20space,-Main%20article%3A%20Dual&text=The%20notation%20for%20the%20continuous,is%20the%20Hahn%E2%80%93Banach%20theorem)- under ''Dual spaces''

Comment: One uses that $Y$ is Banach to say that any weak$^*$-continuous functional on $Y^{**}$ is given by evaluation at a point in $Y$. This is not true if $Y$ is not complete.

Comment: This was my initial thought. However (again..) I cannot see where completeness is used here either: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183869/weak-continuous-linear-functional-is-in-the-predual#2503241

Comment: It is not. The result that the dual of $X^*$ with the weak$^*$-topology is $X$, holds for any locally convex space.

Comment: There is a mistake in the example, when you say "in particular ...". Take for example $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $w_j(n)=0$ if $n<j$, $w_j(n)=j$ otherwise. Then it weak* converges to zero in Y, but $\sum w_j(n)/n^2$ does not.

Comment: @jantomico: after "in particular...", I'm just applying the definition of weak$^∗$-convergence with a concrete sequence in $\ell^1$. In any case, that sequence does not converge weak$^∗$ to zero. For starters, a weak$^*$-convergent sequence is bounded. And even without appealing to theory, consider the sequence $z=(n^{−3/2})∈\ell^1$. You have $$\langle w_j,z\rangle=\sum_{n=j}^\infty\frac j{n^{3/2}}\geq j\,\int_j^\infty t^{-3/2}\,dt=2\sqrt j\xrightarrow[j\to\infty]{}\infty.$$

Comment: I might be wrong, but you suggested using the $\sigma(l_\infty,X=c_{00})$ topology which is not the same as the $\sigma(l_\infty,l_1)$ topology. The sequence I gave is weak* convergent with the first topology, since given $x\in X$ arbitrary then $x(n)=0$ for $n>n_0$ and $\Sigma x(n)w_j(n)=0$ for $j>n_0$. Since $(1/n^2)$ is not in the dual of the space, the functional is not continuous.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I'll try to find time to think about this later today.

Comment: @jantomico: based on your observation I have revised [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1832837/22857) which now I'm led to believe works for any pair of normed spaces. I would like you to take a look before I edit this answer to reflect that an example like this cannot exist.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to answer, your response looks fine to me. Also, it is quite illustrative, great job!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!